# Translating WebApp with vue-i18n without changing URL

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

What would be the best implementation of i18n. It's for a webapp so I don't want to update the url based on locale.

I am using nuxt frameworks so I researched nuxt-i18n but that's not possible without updating the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to create a simple example, but we can still improve.

In this approach, I tried to use cookies instead of the path, and to do so I need to make a refresh page when we switch languages or else our components wouldn't load the new translations.

Check here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/example-i18n-mo8t7?fontsize=14

Comment: Thanks! I implimented this in my Nuxt application and it works whitout any problems! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

in nuxt.config.js/ts

```
i18n: {
...
strategy: 'no_prefix',
...

}
```

to change the locale, use something like:

```
changeLocale() {
  this.$i18n.setLocale(this.$i18n.locale === 'en' ? 'tr' : 'en')
}
```